# Is oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource.getConnection() multi-thread safe?

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, ucp

Can we call oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource.getConnection() from multiple threads ?

Answer (score 1):

oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource.getConnection() API is used to borrow a connection from the ucp pool. So, yes you can call it from multiple threads.